# Duplicate a chunk of HTML code with button press using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a website that has Multiple choice questions. I want a feature which enables the user to add question with a button press. After pressing the button a editable MCQ template should appear. I have done the coding for a question which is like this

```
<div id="mcq">
    <div id="question">
        <p class="Q1" data_opt="A"><b>Q1.</b>What is the next number in the series 1,2,3,...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="options">
        <div id="optList">
            <p id="optId" class="opt ans" data-opt="A">4</p>
            <p id="optId" class="opt" data-opt="B">5</p>
            <p id="optId" class="opt" data-opt="C">6</p>
            <p id="optId" class="opt" data-opt="D">7</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="stats">
        <ul class="stat_list">
            <li><p class="btn">Like</p></li>
            <li><p class="like_counter">20</p></li>
            <li><p class="done">Check Answer</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to duplicate this code using jQuery and edit the text there after. This greatly reduces repeated coding. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Unrelated, but shouldn't the data attributes be `data-opt`?

Comment: @ Dave Newton you are right. I ignored them since I wasn't using them. Will edit. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Also unrelated, but it seems more like since you want to populate the question it'd be cleaner to use a templating engine and just pass in a JSON structure for populating the data. I'd also recommend against giving away the answer with a simple 'Inspect Element'.

Comment: To set the html of an element use: [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Suggest you look into reactJS, this is work that would be better done using the shadowDOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should create a fragment and inject it something like this:

```
var options="";
var frag = ['<div id="optlist">'];
    for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++){
          options+= '<p id=optId'+i+' class="opt" opt-data="'+anwsers[i].data+'">'+anwsers[i].answer+'</p>';
    }
frag.push(options);
frag.push('</div>');
$(".options").append(frag.join(" "));
```

also, you need to make those id's unique optId1, optId2, etc or use classes

Comment: Thanks your answer was helpful. Please help me add <p> elements as shown above including the class attributes.

Comment: I edited the fields for p tags. the answers array should be an array of objects collected when the users create the answers they want. So should look like answers = [{data:"A", answer:"1"},{...}] if my answer helped, please vote it up. Thanks